# Is it possible to reference non-data directory in Firefox addon?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

In my firefox addon code, if i reference a file inside `data` directory, all works fine:

```
var button = widget.Widget({
  id: 'foo',
  label: 'bar',
  contentURL: data.url('icon.png'),
  onClick: function() {
    tabs.open(data.url('control.html'));
  },
});
```

But if i put same file into `foo` directory, it's can't be referenced anymore (not opened as webpage, not displayed as image etc):

```
var button = widget.Widget({
  id: 'foo',
  label: 'bar',
  contentURL: data.url('icon.png'),
  onClick: function() {
    tabs.open(data.url('../foo/control.html'));
  },
});
```

In documentation it's stated that `data.url()` works relative to `data` directory, but it's unclear is it works `only` for `data` directory or not? Is it possible to use other top-level directories, or i have no options and need to put all my addon files inside `data` directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. But you can't use the data method.

I don't know how to get the self path to the jar file in SDK. But once you get the self path then you can load that file.

actualy on some thought:
Probably do a console.log(data.url('control.html')) that should give you the location to your data folder something like:
jar://blah/blah/blah/data/control.html

so do string maniuplation and remove the data to just get
jar://blah/blah/blah/

then on to that add jar://blah/blah/blah/foo/stuff in foo.html

something like if foo is in the same directory as data folder. just do a console.log of the data.url('icong.png') and post here and i can help you with the string manipulation